# Nav Menu is not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the source from a Nav Menu website and I am trying to use it in my tumblr, but for some reason the responsive part of the menu (media query) it is not collapsing. When I do it locally it collapses fine, but once I add it to jsfiddle or tumblr it does not collapse.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/

CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;

  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: add jquery in fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/

Comment: [As soon as you add jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/3/) it seems to work fine.

Comment: I am so sorry about this but where did you add Jquery?

Comment: in jsFiddle add it in the left hand side side bar under "Frameworks & Extensions" here is the working link https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/6/

Comment: If you have checked using developer tool of browser( like inspect element in chrome) then you will get that the jquery does not loaded,  and that is the main problem why your code does not worked. And how to add jquery you can get from answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its not working because it donnt have jQuery library. There can be any other issue you can check it on browser consloe..

To check console (Chrome Browser). follow these steps

```
step 1: right click on page in browser and click on Inspect Element
step 2: click on cnsole tag.
```

You can check error in browser console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try to add `Jquery` along with your script like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b1jczua7/4/)**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
```